# How to install PostgreSQL 9.3.3 client on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I should do

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.3
```

However this would install the latest version (9.3.16).
I want to install 9.3.3 How do I do that?

if I do:

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.3.3
```

I get:

> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.3.3
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.3.3'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.3.3'

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you want to install an outdated version full of bugs? There is a reason 9.3.3 got up to 9.3.16... That's 13 patch rounds fixing hundreds of bugs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens Because we are working on 9.3.3 We will upgrade but not at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by     following the package name with an equals (=) and the version of the package to select.

Example:
apt-get install postgresql=9.3.3

https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Comment: Looks like official mirror contains only 9.3.16 so you have to either find a mirror that contains 9.3.3 or get .deb file manually and install it. For example, from this place:
https://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/archive-packages.jsp

Then you can either do `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` optionally running `sudo apt-get install -f` afterwards to fix broken dependencies or

put your deb file to /var/cache/apt/archives/ directory and run `apt-get install package_name`